# Passing Values from jInternalFrame to another jInternalFrame using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jinternalframe

My problem is that I don't know how to pass values from a jInternalFrame to another one.
When I'm on jInternalFrame1, I click a button that open jInternalFrame2, and in this one I need to put some values (string and int), and when I click the "OK" button in jInternalFrame2 I would like to show the values in my jInternalFrame1.
This is how I open the jInternalFrame2 on my jInternalFrame1:

```
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    ConfigureHost ch = new ConfigureHost();      //ConfigureHost is my jInternalFrame2
    jDesktopPane1.add(ch);        //Yeah I have a DesktopPane on my jInternalFrame1
    ch.setVisible(true);
```

Anyone got some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a constructor in your internalframe and pass relevant values when you creating that frame object.